# Busqueda de estructura, dentro de estructura en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer en C una busqueda, la condición, es que mientras el COD_ART, no existe, me tire un alerta, y si no, que continue el programa. Intenté hacerlo de varias formas, pero no resulta, y cuando quiero ver el listado de la consulta, me aparece basura en vez del valor que guardé. Además, tengo problemas con la función de "actualizar" y que se supone que debe restarme la cantidad de stock disponible con la cantidad que se pidió, pero no lo actualiza. Se que debe tener muchos errores, pero trato de aprender como hacer este tipo de cosas, ya que recién estoy comenzando a programar en C.

Acá ingreso los datos, busco si existe el articulo y verifico que el stock que tengo no sea menor al pedido hecho, no me funciona el buscador ni tampoco la consulta me muestra correctamente la el COD_ART

```
typedef struct stock{
    int cod_art;
    char talle;
    int cant_prendas;
}t_stock;
typedef struct pedidos{
    int num_cliente;
    int cant_solicitada;
    t_stock vstock;
}t_pedidos;
int main()
{
    int continuar,x,y;
    t_stock vstock[max];
    t_pedidos vpedidos[max];
    do{
        menu();
        scanf("%d",&continuar);
        system("cls");
        switch(continuar){
        case 1:x=ingresarStock(vstock);
            break;
        case 2:y=ingresarePedidos(vpedidos,vstock);
            break;
        case 3:mostrarStock(vstock,x);
            break;
        case 4:mostrarPedidos(vpedidos,y);
        actualizar(vpedidos,vstock,y);
            break;
        case 0: printf("Fin del programa. Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar\n\n");
            break;
        default: printf("Error. Opcion no disponible\n");
            break;
        }
    }while(continuar!=0);
    return 0;
}
int ingresarStock(t_stock vstock[]){
    int continuar,contador=0;
    do{
        printf("\n--------------------INGRESO DE STOCK--------------------\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese el codigo de articulo:");
        scanf("%d",&vstock[contador].cod_art);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese el talle:");
        gets(&vstock[contador].talle);
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de prendas:");
        scanf("%d",&vstock[contador].cant_prendas);
        printf("\n--Desea agregar otro dato?1 si - 0 no\n");
        scanf("%d",&continuar);
        contador++;
        system("cls");
    }while(continuar!=0);
    return contador;
}
int mostrarStock(t_stock vstock[],int l){
    int i;
        printf("\n--------------------LISTADO DE STOCK--------------------\n\n");
        printf("CODIGO ARTICULO \t TALLE \t CANTIDAD DE PRENDAS\n");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        printf("\t%d",vstock[i].cod_art);
        printf("\t\t   %c",vstock[i].talle);
        printf("\t\t %d\n",vstock[i].cant_prendas);
        }
}
int ingresarePedidos(t_pedidos vpedidos[],t_stock vstock[]){
    int continuar,i=0,art=0,solicitada=0,disponible=0;
    do{
        printf("\n--------------------INGRESO DE PEDIDOS--------------------\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese el numero de cliente:");
        scanf("%d",&vpedidos[i].num_cliente);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese el codigo de articulo:");
        scanf("%d",&art);
        while(art!=vstock[i].cod_art){
            printf("Error. El articulo de campera no exite - Ingrese otro\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&art);
        }
        vstock[i].cod_art=art;
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese el talle:");
        gets(&vpedidos[i].vstock.talle);
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de prendas solicitadas:");
        scanf("%d",&vpedidos[i].cant_solicitada);
        system("cls");
        while(vpedidos[i].cant_solicitada>vstock[i].cant_prendas){
            printf("\n\n--No hay Stock suficiente.\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&vpedidos[i].cant_solicitada);
        }
        printf("--Desea ingresar otro dato? 1 si - 0 no\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&continuar);
        i++;
    }while(continuar!=0);
    return i;
}
```

Acá en esta funcion aparte, actualizo el stock(es decir, resto el stock que tengo disponible con la cantidad pedida) pero no funciona correctamente, directamente me reemplaza el valor del stock, por la cantidad que solicito:

```
int actualizar(t_pedidos vpedidos[],t_stock vstock[],int l){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        vstock[i].cant_prendas=vstock[i].cant_prendas-vpedidos[i].cant_solicitada;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está declarada `max`?

Comment: Max esta declarado en un #define arriba de la función, me olvide de aclarar eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `i` **siempre** es 0:

```
int continuar,i=0,art=0,solicitada=0,disponible=0;
//            ~~~

do{
    printf("\n--------------------INGRESO DE PEDIDOS--------------------\n\n");
    printf("Ingrese el numero de cliente:");
    scanf("%d",&vpedidos[i].num_cliente);
    //                   ~ i=0
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el codigo de articulo:");
    scanf("%d",&art);
    while(art!=vstock[i].cod_art){
    //                ~ i=0
        printf("Error. El articulo de campera no exite - Ingrese otro\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&art);
    }
```

En el primer caso, `i` debería apuntar **al primer registro libre** de `vpedidos`. Ignoro cómo vas a ser capaz de identificar el primer pedido libre. Podrías inicializar el vector con `num_cliente` a `-1` (o cualquier otro valor no válido) y usar eso para localizar los registros libres.

En el segundo caso deberías iterar **por todos los elementos** de `vstock` hasta dar con el artículo pedido o llegar al final del array.

Algo así:

```
int indice_articulo;

while(1)
{
  for( indice_articulo=0; indice_articulo<max; indice_articulo++ )
  {
    if( vstock[indice_articulo].cod_art == art )
      break;
  }

  if( indice_articulo == max )
  {
    printf("Error. El articulo de campera no exite - Ingrese otro\n\n");
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Genial, ahora comprendo y lo pude solucionar, gracias! 